# Transferring license keys when restoring from backup

Tags: microsoft-office

I've got Ubuntu 13.10 and I was using LibreOffice which ended up being quite problematic as I didn't find it very intuitive to use. I found that I could use wine to put Microsoft office on Ubuntu. However I'm planning on making another computer and transferring data from my MBP to the computer. Will the license key transfer so I don't have to buy another license key for it?

Comment: If its in Wine, you may be able to copy over the `~/.wine` folder *(which contains a sort of virtual C drive)* so it is on the other machine. However, windows & changing hardware does not always mix....

Comment: Could you please make that a comment instead of an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @rajlego this is a comment... answers are below.

Comment: Sorry I got mixed up I wanted him to make the comment an answer so I could mark it as correct.

Comment: Made the comment an answer, or the answer a comment... something like that :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its in [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/), you may be able to copy over the `~/.wine`folder *(which contains a sort of virtual C drive)* so it is on the other machine. However, windows & changing hardware does not always mix....

You may want to make sure both computers are running the same version of Wine, for that you should be able to use `wine --version`.